# Azure Notifications hub .net api not working async

Tags: c#, ios, .net, azure, async-await

I have followed [this](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-get-started/)  tutorial to create a push notification hub for an IOS app.

When i run the code

```
private static async void SendNotificationAsync()
{
     NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(host, "sideview", false);
     var alert = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Hello\"}}";
     await hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(alert);
}
```

from static void Main(string[] args) of  a console program , nothing happens, the console just stops.

If I use

```
private static  void SendNotificationAsync()
{
     NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(host, "sideview", false);
     var alert = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Hello\"}}";
     hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(alert).Wait();
}
```

everythings works fine

Update

As Yuval Itzchakov said in the answer bellow, Console Application's main method can't be marked async, so the async method will not be waited

Comment: You need to show how you are calling these methods - include the code in your question.

Comment: I'm going to take a punt that you are calling this from a method which can't await this method as it is an async void, so there is no way of awaiting method to complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Console Application's main method can't be marked `async`. Hence, you need to explicitly use `Task.Wait` or `Task.Result` on the async operation to make sure the consoles main method doesn't terminate, hence closing the entire process.

I am assuming the call is along the lines of:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Do some stuff
    SendNotificationAsync();
}
```

You need to do two things:

1. Change `SendNotificationAsync` to `async Task` instead of `async void` so you can `Wait` on the returned Task. Note `async void` is ment solely for the compatibility of async event handlers:

   ```
   private static async Task SendNotificationAsync()
   {
       NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(host, "sideview", false);
       var alert = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Hello\"}}";
       await hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(alert);
   }
   ```
2. Use `Task.Wait` at the top of your call stack:

   ```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      // Do some stuff
      SendNotificationAsync().Wait();
   }
   ```

This will work fine with a Console Application. This approach is **NOT** recommended for any application having a custom `SynchronizationContext` other than the default `ThreadPoolSynchronizationContext`. Always use `await` all the way down in those type of applications.

Comment: So if i would use the async method in the web api "ecosystem", I should have any problems with                              private static async Task SendNotificationAsync()
{
    NotificationHubClient hub = NotificationHubClient.CreateClientFromConnectionString(host, "sideview", false);
    var alert = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"Hello\"}}";
    await hub.SendAppleNativeNotificationAsync(alert);
} ?

Comment: Why do you assume you'd have any problem?

Comment: I wanted to say i shouldn't have a problem

Comment: You should be perfectly fine.